# Google Sheets | Search Range for substring in referenced cell and if found, then "Y"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having trouble finding a working formula to will search for the substring in a referenced cell ($A6 from Tracking 3) from the range ('AC 3'!$B4:B) and if it returns true, then a "Y" will show.

I currently have a google sheet that is used to track webinar attendance by searching the range (copied and pasted chat messages) for the referenced attendee same, and if the attendee's name is found, a "Y" is placed in that cell. The sheet is currently functional for our prior webinar platform, as when the chat messages are pasted, the attendee's name is isolated within its own cell, however, the new platform copies with the following format: "From 'attendee name' to All Panelist 00:00 PM". In the code I currently have, it is not recognized that the attendees' names are found within the ranges.

For a visual, I have "Y" input for the name Dylan Payne to show the end outcome I am looking for. I have tried the functions SEARCH, REGEXMATCH, and MATCH. I believe the SEARCH function is where my answer lies, but I'm having trouble reaching my desired outcome. If anyone is able to provide some additional feedback, it would be extremely appreciated.

I also use some google AppsScript, if there is a way to use that to isolate the attendees' names within the cell.

[Tracking 3][image: 1]

[AC 3][image: 2]

Comment: Show the expected output.

Comment: The desired outcome is to have a "Y" appear in the respective cell (D6:AB) if they sent a chat, which those chat records are pasted into columns in the sheet "AC 3".

Comment: Under what circumstance would `D6` be `Y` , but `E6:AB6` wouldn't?

Comment: So D6 should have a "Y" if the name "Billy Madison" is found within any substring from the range 'AC 3'!$B$4:B. D7 would be looking for "Billy Madison" within any substrings from 'AC 3'!$C$4:C. Currently, the formula is only returning "Y" if the referenced cell (the attendees' name) is isolated in its own cell.

Answer (score 0):

#### Add Y to range with searched for substrings

```
function fss() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive():
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("AC3");
  const sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("Tracking");
  const sA = sh0.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();//names
  const rg = sh.getRange("C4:N" + sh.getLastRow());//search range
  sa.forEach((s,i) => {
    rg.createTextFinder(s).matchEntireCell(false).findAll().forEach(r => {
      r.setValue(r.getValue() + "Y")
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that AppsScript will work, because "String1", "String2", etc. are referenced cells for the attendees' names, which will vary.

Comment: Just replace those strings with there names.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found a useable code, actually:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(INDEX(FILTER('AC 3'!$B$4:$B,SEARCH($A20,'AC 3'!$B$4:$B)),1)),"Y","")
```

There is one more element I would like to implement from the previous code. In the previous code, it searched for the named range `courseACs`, and if the title (`$A$1`) is found in the name range, it would have a designated number of columns needed for that webinar duration (three columns per hour of duration).

Let's say the webinar title `Ethics` is two hours long and would need six columns for chat records. The formula then looks at the column and if it is in a column that resides after the sixth column for attentiveness tracking (Column K) then `-` will reflect in the cell. The original code is shown below:

```
=IF(IFERROR(E$5<=SEARCH(RIGHT($A$1,LEN($A$1)-15),courseACs,4),true),IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A6,'AC 1'!C$4:C$2000,0))),"Y"," "),"-")
```